# How to read an array element by element

Tags: java, arrays

I am having trouble figuring out how to read through an array with rows and columns and print out the index number & decide whether the element is positive, negative, or zero.

All I've really done was create the array, its a [5][6] array. A few days ago I completed a problem with only 1 row and figured it out, but I'm having trouble translating it to rows and columns together.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you've seen an example in one dimension, you should be able to use the same approach to read a 2D array. Just remember that a 2D array is actually just an array of arrays.

Comment: You can use two for loops and `array.length` and `array[0].lenth` as maximum. Obviously you would not have one index, but two. If you want to have one index you could let it go to 5 * 6 = 30 (exclusive) and then use the `/` integer division and `%` remainder operators to calculate the `x` and `y` indices into the arrays. Note that in Java there is not really a multi-dimensional array, just an array of arrays - so you select an array of integers by indexing the array of arrays.

Comment: You use a for loop in a for loop. I think of 2D arrays like 1D arrays stacked on each other.

Comment: This question is very remedial, you should check the online tutorial for hints, and attempt some code on your own, then post the code that you have attempted. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html